# Big $O$ notation and computations

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, notation

Here all the functions of natural numbers are positive.$p$ is a prime number.
Let $A(n)+B(n)=C(n)+D(n)$ where $B(n)=O(p^{5n})$. $ A(n)$ is always less that or equal to $C(n)$.$D(n)$ is known to be of $O(p^{4n})$. Can I deduce that $C(n)$ is greater or equal to $B(n)+O(p^{4n})$ ?

I arrived in this kind of equation by the following way:
I have an exact sequence of vector spaces $V(n),W(n),P(n)$ over a field $K$.

$V(n)->W(n)->P(n)->0 $ .I complete this exact sequence into $0->M(n)->V(n)->W(n)->P(n)->0 $. Here M(n) is the kernel of the map from $V(n)$ to $W(n)$. Also $A(n), B(n), C(n), D(n) $ are dimension of the vector spaces $M(n),W(n),V(n),P(n)$ respectively. I apply the dimension formula for exact sequence and get the given equality.

Comment: Do you mean is $C(n)\geq B(n) + Cp^{4n}$, i.e. $C(n)=\Omega(B(n)+p^{4n})$?

Comment: Otherwise, saying $C(n)\geq O(p^{4n})$ doesn't make a lot of sense.  Notice that one always uses $f = O(...)$ or $f=\Omega(...)$ not $f\leq O(...)$ (always use $=$ when dealing with asymptotic notation).

Comment: Perhaps you can add to your question (via edit, not delete and re-post) the definition that is given in the paper you posted.  It would help all readers of your question to not have to sift through that text.

Comment: Then in short answer to your question, you cannot deduce any lower bound on $C(n)$.

Comment: Why is that true?

Comment: I looked at the paper and admit I don't understand why the proof on p. 202 proceeds as it does. I would have said that $A\leq B + O(f)$, if it makes any sense at all, is the same as $A = B + O(f)$ (which after all just says that $O(f)$ is an asymptotic upper bound on $A-B$), so the argument "proving" $A\geq B + O(f)$ seems, at best, completely unnecessary. Perhaps there's more here than meets my eye.

Comment: Because $B(n)=O(p^{5n})$ doesn't preclude $B(n)=1$ for all $n$ and "mysterious" $+O(p^{4n})$ term doesn't preclude the mysterious unknown function from being identically 1.  Then all you're asserting is that $C(n)$ is at least 2...